# Read character with cin (C++)

Tags: c++, xcode

I try to make this code work i XCode 6.01. Its a small program that takes a number of double and a char and then prints the char.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{

    char c=' ';
    double d = 0;


    cin >> d >> c;

    cout << "The char is: "<< c;

    return 0;
}
```

The result of input "2d" is:  `"The char is:  Program ended with exit code: 0"`
As you can see "d" is not shown.

If I try with input of "2m" it works. `(The char is: mProgram ended with exit code: 0)`

Can anybody help?

Comment: a space, or a *spaceship* maybe? i.e. try `"2 d"`...

Comment: What is the problem? "d" is not shown?

Comment: Consider also printing the value of `d`.

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1: when you send "2d" to cin, you are only assigning input value to one variable. If you want to assign two variables add space in between ("2 d"), or assign them separately: type 2, hit enter, type d, hit enter again.

Problem 2: cin doesn't do type checking. When you assign an invalid type to double or int, you will get undesirable behaviours.

If you remove the char input from your code, and only assign your input to double d:

```
int main ()
{

    char c=' ';
    double d = 0;


    // cin >> d >> c;
    cin >> d
    // cout << "The char is: "<< c;
    cout << "d = " << d << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For input 2d: result --> d = 0
For input 2m: result --> d = 2
For input 2o: result --> d = 2
For input 2a: result --> d = 0
For input 2p: result --> d = 0
For input 2q: result --> d = 2

As you can see sometimes cin doesn't know how to handle the input and just ignore it completely. 
And sometimes cin can recognise the numerical part of the input and store it in variable d, and if you add cin >> c after d, it will put the remaining part in char c.

More explanation and code sample:[Using cin to get user input](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/6046/)

Comment: The reason I am confused about this is that Strousrup in his own book about programming and principles in C++, keep using this technique. And for him it obviously work. I do not know which compiler he use, maybe that makes the difference. But thanks, I'll follow your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Compile the code with GCC and the program will work as expected.

cin >> d >> c; // d (double) is separated from c (char)